# Some settings for Sequelize associations not work

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I encountered difficulties while setting up a database foreign key using Sequelize ORM.

I want to set association on message_tb model. RECEIVE_TO works well association settings. But DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX and ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX association setting not work.

Below is my code.

message_tb.js

```
'use strict'

const utils = require(process.env.PWD + '/utils');
const globalVar = require(process.env.PWD + '/api-global');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const message_tb = sequelize.define('message_tb', {
    MESSAGE_IDX: {
      field: 'MESSAGE_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    MESSAGE_TYPE: {
      field: 'MESSAGE_TYPE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false
    },
    MESSAGE_TITLE: {
      field: 'MESSAGE_TITLE',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false
    },
    MESSAGE_ITEM_TYPE: {
      field: 'MESSAGE_ITEM_TYPE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false
    },
    MESSAGE_ITEM: {
      field: 'MESSAGE_ITEM',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false
    },
    DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX: {
      field: 'DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX: {
      field: 'ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    },
    RECEIVE_TO: {
      field: 'RECEIVE_TO',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false
    },
    EXPIRED_DATE: {
      field: 'EXPIRED_DATE',
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
    }
  }, {
    // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
    // so updatedAt will be updated_at
    underscored: false,

    // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
    // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
    // if you don't want that, set the following
    freezeTableName: true,

    // define the table's name
    tableName: 'MESSAGE_TB'
  });

  message_tb.associate = function (models) {
    message_tb.belongsTo(models.user_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'RECEIVE_TO',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    message_tb.belongsTo(models.log_user_buy_dia_item_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    message_tb.belongsTo(models.log_user_buy_etc_item_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  };

  return message_tb;
};
```

log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.js

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const log_user_buy_dia_item_tb = sequelize.define('log_user_buy_dia_item_tb', {
    LOG_IDX: {
      field: 'LOG_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    DEVICE_ID: {
      field: 'DEVICE_ID',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    STORE_ITEM_IDX: {
      field: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    BUY_DATE: {
      field: 'BUY_DATE',
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW')
    },
    GET_DATE_AT_MESSAGE: {
      field: 'GET_DATE_AT_MESSAGE',
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
    // so updatedAt will be updated_at
    underscored: false,

    // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
    // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
    // if you don't want that, set the following
    freezeTableName: true,

    //// define the table's name
    tableName: 'LOG_USER_BUY_DIA_ITEM_TB'
  });

  log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.hasOne(models.message_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  }

  log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.belongsTo(models.user_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.belongsTo(models.store_dia_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      targetKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  };

  return log_user_buy_dia_item_tb;
};
```

log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.js

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const log_user_buy_etc_item_tb = sequelize.define('log_user_buy_etc_item_tb', {
    LOG_IDX: {
      field: 'LOG_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    DEVICE_ID: {
      field: 'DEVICE_ID',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    STORE_ITEM_IDX: {
      field: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    BUY_DATE: {
      field: 'BUY_DATE',
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW')
    },
    GET_DATE_AT_MESSAGE: {
      field: 'GET_DATE_AT_MESSAGE',
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ONLY_ONE_BUY_FLG: {
      field: 'ONLY_ONE_BUY_FLG',
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
    // so updatedAt will be updated_at
    underscored: false,

    // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
    // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
    // if you don't want that, set the following
    freezeTableName: true,

    //// define the table's name
    tableName: 'LOG_USER_BUY_ETC_ITEM_TB'
  });

  log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.hasMany(models.message_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  }

  log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.belongsTo(models.user_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.belongsTo(models.store_etc_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      targetKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  };

  return log_user_buy_etc_item_tb;
};
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(process.env.PWD + '/configs/sequelize.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

user_tb.js

```
'use strict'

const globalVar = require(process.env.PWD + '/api-global');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const user_tb = sequelize.define('user_tb', {
    DEVICE_ID: {
      field: 'DEVICE_ID',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ANDROID_ID: {
      field: 'ANDROID_ID',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      unique: true,
      allowNull: true
    },
    APPLE_ID: {
      field: 'APPLE_ID',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      unique: true,
      allowNull: true
    },
    NICKNAME: {
      field: 'NICKNAME',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },

    USER_LV: {
      field: 'USER_LV',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    EXP: {
      field: 'EXP',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    LV_HP: {
      field: 'LV_HP',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_ATTACK_POWER: {
      field: 'LV_ATTACK_POWER',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_ATTACK_SPEED: {
      field: 'LV_ATTACK_SPEED',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_CRITICAL_PERCENT: {
      field: 'LV_CRITICAL_PERCENT',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_CRITICAL_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_CRITICAL_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_COOLTIME_DECREASE: {
      field: 'LV_COOLTIME_DECREASE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    LV_FIRE_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_FIRE_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_ICE_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_ICE_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_LIGHTNING_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_LIGHTNING_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_WIND_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_WIND_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LV_VISION_DAMAGE: {
      field: 'LV_VISION_DAMAGE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    GOLD: {
      field: 'GOLD',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    DIA: {
      field: 'DIA',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LAST_STAGE_NUM: {
      field: 'LAST_STAGE_NUM',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LAST_WAVE_NUM: {
      field: 'LAST_WAVE_NUM',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    ELEMENT_POINT: {
      field: 'ELEMENT_POINT',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    STATUS_POINT: {
      field: 'STATUS_POINT',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    LOCKED_SLOT_PASSIVE: {
      field: 'LOCKED_SLOT_PASSIVE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: globalVar.initLockedPassiveSlotCnt
    },
    LOCKED_SLOT_ACTIVE: {
      field: 'LOCKED_SLOT_ACTIVE',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: globalVar.initLockedActiveSlotCnt
    }
  }, {
    // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
    // so updatedAt will be updated_at
    underscored: false,

    // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
    // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
    // if you don't want that, set the following
    freezeTableName: true,

    // define the table's name
    tableName: 'USER_TB'
  });

  user_tb.associate = function (models) {
    user_tb.hasOne(models.user_ban_info_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.user_item_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.message_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'RECEIVE_TO',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.user_skill_passive_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.user_skill_active_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasOne(models.cloud_sync_info_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.log_user_get_random_box_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.log_user_buy_dia_item_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    user_tb.hasMany(models.log_user_buy_etc_item_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  };

  return user_tb;
};
```

[my phpmyadmin designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEdi9.png)

Comment: What exaclty goes wrong? Any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX and ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX at message_tb.js is association not work. but RECEIVE_TO field association is work very well...

Comment: I have read about `association not work` in the question. What does it mean? You get an error when include this association in sequelize query or something else?

Comment: There is no error. But In the phpmyadmin designer view, the association is not set.

Comment: So you use sequlize.sync() ? Show how and where you call it

Comment: I am not call sequelize.sync.. I use the default generated index.js. 
Added index.js and phpmyadmin designer screens.

Comment: The question is how did you create tables?

Comment: I just change flag force:true at sequelize.json(config file) and npm start..

Comment: please see answer below

Comment: thx. I left a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten associations in log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.js and log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.js by redefining **associate** prop.
Correct them like this:

log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.js

```
log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.hasOne(models.message_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.belongsTo(models.user_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    log_user_buy_dia_item_tb.belongsTo(models.store_dia_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      targetKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  }
```

log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.js

```
log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.associate = function(models) {
    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.hasMany(models.message_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX',
      targetKey: 'LOG_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.belongsTo(models.user_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      targetKey: 'DEVICE_ID',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });

    log_user_buy_etc_item_tb.belongsTo(models.store_etc_tb, {
      foreignKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      targetKey: 'STORE_ITEM_IDX',
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is the way I have already tried. It doesn't work at all....

Comment: check you have only one `associate` prop with associations in each model. Check associations prop in each registered model at the `db.sequelize = sequelize;` line

Comment: What about registered models? Are there all defined associations exist in registered models in `associations` prop?

Comment: Can you look at registered model `message_tb` at the line `db.sequelize = sequelize`in db['message_tb'].associations? What keys and objects does it have?

Comment: console.log (db ['message_tb']. associations); I tried to print As a result...{ user_tb: user_tb,
  log_user_buy_dia_item_tb: log_user_buy_dia_item_tb,
  log_user_buy_etc_item_tb: log_user_buy_etc_item_tb }

Comment: My database is mariadb and I look up the relevant settings with phpmyadmin.
The sequelize association seems to be established. Is there any reason why the results are different in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MESSAGE_TB` (`MESSAGE_IDX` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment , `MESSAGE_TYPE` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `MESSAGE_TITLE` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `MESSAGE_ITEM_TYPE` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `MESSAGE_ITEM` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `RECEIVE_TO` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `EXPIRED_DATE` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (`MESSAGE_IDX`), FOREIGN KEY (`RECEIVE_TO`) REFERENCES `USER_TB` (`DEVICE_ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: In the database initialization console, the ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX field and the ETC_BUY_LOG_IDX field are excluded from foreign key settings.

Comment: From MariaDB foreign key doc: `The referenced columns must be a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index.`

Comment: Also if a column indicated in targetKey is a prmary key try to remove this option from an association definition

Comment: I remove primaryKey and autoIncrement option. and add unique: true option.. this code very work well. So, why does the RECEIVE_TO field work? DEVICE_ID field have primaryKey:true and autoIncrement:true option...

Comment: You didn't show `user` model in the question so can't compare

Comment: The device_id association in the USER model works from message_tb to RECEIVE_TO. But I don't know why LOG_IDX should be unique.

Comment: No, don't remove `primaryKey` and `autoIncrement` from a model, remove `targetKey` option from association definition

Comment: In association option, I did something like foreignKey: 'DIA_BUY_LOG_IDX', onDelete: 'restrict', onUpdate: 'restrict' but it doesn't work. Only targetKey was excluded.